# celluloid: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpv.so.2: undefined symbol: av_packet_side_data_get, version LIBAVCODEC_60

Tags: mpv, celluloid

I'm using Devuan GNU/Linux Excalibur, with the debian-multimedia.org repository for Debian trixie (= the equivalent of excalibur but with systemd).

I'm trying to run the celluloid media player, version 0.26; which uses libmpv.so.2.2.0 (although the package version is reported as libmpv 0.37.0-1). When I run it, I get:

```
celluloid: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpv.so.2: undefined symbol: av_packet_side_data_get, version LIBAVCODEC_60
```

I have nothing in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

I'll also note that when I try and *build* celluloid 0.26, I get the same link error.

Why is this happening and how can resolve it?